# How can I use a variable for assigning an additional header?

Tags: ios, append, authorization, token, nsurlsessionconfiguration

I have a variable which holds 3f78124e98419428b7. I want to replace this string with my variable.
Does anyone know how can I do this?

```
[config setHTTPAdditionalHeaders:@{@"Authorization":@" Token token=\"3f78124e98419428b7\""}];
```

Comment: `stringWithFormat` ?

Comment: can you explain more @paulw

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the NSString method `stringWihFormat`?

Comment: @Paulw11 thx alot . I read it and I found the solution.

Comment: "Give a man an answer and you help him once; teach a man to read the documentation and you help him for a lifetime."